# как объединить в два запроса в одну таблицу

Tags: mysql, sql

Здравствуйте такая проблема есть два запроса по отдельность работают, а вот как их объединить left join или еще как не знаю всем спасибо, вот запросы

rec и id одинаковый идентификатор, то есть к первому запросу добавить поля fullName, imgRealtorSmall, fileNameSmall

```html
@user = 1;
SELECT IF(sender=@user,addressee, sender) rec,
       max(date) last_date,
       substr(max(concat(date,message)),20) last_msg,
       sum(addressee_status=0) not_seen
  FROM chat
 WHERE addressee=@user
 GROUP BY rec
 
 SELECT id, fullName, imgRealtorSmall, fileNameSmall FROM realtor
```

пытаюсь делать так но пишет ошибку SQL Error (1064): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE chat.addressee=@user 
GROUP BY rec' at line 1 
То есть первую строку открывает а остальные нет и в поле not_seen суммирует все записи разбиение не присходит

```html
 
 
SET @user=236;
 
SELECT IF(chat.sender=@user,chat.addressee, chat.sender) rec,
   max(chat.date) last_date,
   substr(max(concat(date,chat.message)),20) last_msg,
   sum(chat.addressee_status=0) not_seen,
   realtor.fullName, 
  realtor.imgRealtorSmall, 
  realtor.fileNameSmall
 
FROM chat
INNER JOIN realtor ON chat.sender = realtor.id;

WHERE chat.addressee=@user 
GROUP BY rec
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я всё сделал если кому полезно будет, суть скрипта что он видит у кого сколько не прочитанных сообщений

```html
SELECT IF(sender=:user,addressee,sender) rec, // проверяет условие так условие 1 параметр 2параметр истина 3 ложь
max(date) last_date,//ищет последнюю дату 
substr(max(concat(date,message)),20) last_msg, // объединяю дату с сообщением что бы не было проблем с повторяющим ид сообщений
sum(addressee_status=0) not_seen, // суммирую статус не прочитанных 
realtor.fullName, // добавляю данные из таблицы realtor
realtor.imgRealtorSmall,// добавляю данные из таблицы realtor
realtor.fileNameSmall // добавляю данные из таблицы realtor
FROM chat 
INNER JOIN realtor ON sender = realtor.id // говорю что с чем должно сравниваться
WHERE addressee=:user  // условие что показываются все сообщения, где в входящих прописан юзер исходящего 
GROUP BY rec // группирую запрос
```